User's cant control or select a letter in native base input with KeyboardAvoidingView (only for android)
I'm encountering an issue with the Native Base Input component in a React Native expo app when used within a Keyboard Avoiding View.
In android the user can write in the input but cant drag/select letters or words in the input (I mean he can write but lets say he got a mistake in the string he want to fix that he must to delete the text until he get into this letter, change it and must write the rest of the text again,he cant choose this spesifc letter to start fix this)
This is the input componnent:
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native';
import UserContext from '@/src/context/UserContext';
import { COLORS, SIZES, rgbaColor } from '@/src/constants/theme';
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import React, { useState, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import { FormControl, Input, KeyboardAvoidingView, Text } from 'native-base';

const TitleInput = () => {
  const isOldDevice = Platform.constants['Release'] < 12;
  const keyboardBehavior = !isOldDevice ? 'position' : null;
  const [valueText, setValueText] = useState('');
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const { setTitle } = useContext(UserContext);

  const handleBlur = useCallback(() => setIsFocused(false), []);
  const handleFocus = useCallback(() => setIsFocused(true), []);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    value => {
      if (value.length <= 100) setValueText(value);
    },
    [] // Dependencies should be stable
  );

  const handleEndEditing = useCallback(
    e => {
      const text = e?.nativeEvent?.text;
      if (text && text.length <= 100) setTitle(text);
    },
    [setTitle] // Keep dependencies minimal and stable
  );

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 75 : 55}
      behavior={keyboardBehavior}
    >
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: COLORS.pureWhite }}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            marginX={4}
            maxLength={100}
            textAlign="left"
            borderRadius="full"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onChangeText={handleChange}
            onEndEditing={handleEndEditing}
            placeholder="Stream Title"
            color={COLORS.darkestGray}
            backgroundColor={COLORS.pureWhite}
            padding={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 4 : 3}
            fontSize={moderateScale(SIZES.extend.regular, 0.1)}
            marginBottom={Platform.select({
              android: isFocused ? 4 : 2,
              ios: isFocused ? SIZES.small : 4,
            })}
            InputRightElement={
              <Text
                paddingTop={5}
                paddingRight={3}
                color={rgbaColor(COLORS.darkestGray, 0.5)}
                fontSize={moderateScale(SIZES.small, 0.1)}
              >
                {valueText.length}/100
              </Text>
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default TitleInput;


When remove the KeyboardAvoidingView then the user can do the behivor I want (select some letter inside the text)
When I take the KeyboardAvoidingView to the parent componnent the behivor I want works but the behibvor on the parent its not want I want to (make all the page scrolling when input focus)
My goal is to keep the keyboardAvoidingView in the titleInput componnent and the users can control the input text
*On iOS works fine
